# Compare strings in two text files

Tags: file, text, cmd, compare

I've been checking every where and i cannot seem to find the resource I need.

Everything I've found so far only compares the entire file but that's not what I am looking for.

I've seen tools such as 'File Compare' for cmd to help but how it does the comparison does not meet the need.

```
FC [filepath1] [filepath2]
```

Is there a way for me to do this.

Take the first line of a text file and compare it with the every line of the 2nd file and output the matching file by creating a new text file with the name of the file and populate it with >Name of file (first text file) >All the matched file (from 2nd file). Then it goes back to the 2nd line of the first text file and compares that with every line on the 2nd file and and creates another text file doing the same thing until the first file becomes empty.

The way I have gottten all the files in a text file is by running the command below.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Documents\Projects\audio -Recurse | Select-Object @{n='File'; e={$_.Name + "," + $_.LastWriteTime}} | Out-File "D:\Documents\Projects\audio\Log.txt"
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Documents\Projects\video -Recurse | Select-Object @{n='File'; e={$_.Name + "," + $_.LastWriteTime}} | Out-File "D:\Documents\Projects\Video\Log.txt"
```

I'll be comparing the name of the video file in the first text document, with every name of the audio files in the 2nd text file.

some video have about 2 audios others about 8 and they all have the same name. Im already looking for a way i can cut the last 3 characters from the file name.

name are written like this

somefilm_v1.mxf

somefilm_a1.mxf

somefilm_a2.mxf

somefilm_a3.mxf

v1 refers to video 1 and a1 refers to audio 1. FileName_ is same, just the 2 characters a*/v1 is different. so im researching on way to not check the last 2/3 characters of the file name. might have to increase it to 5 if it checks the file format as well.

If this can be done with batch as well before the comparison happens, it would be great as well.

I'm looking for it being done in batch if possible please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop over the contents of a file. Best to do this is a `for /f` loop. But you don't even need a file. Just loop over all `*_v1.mxf` files instead. Then split the movie name and add all `<MovieName_a*>` file names:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%a in (*_v1.*) do (
  set "all="%%a""
  for /f "delims=_" %%b in ("%%~na") do (
    for %%c in ("%%b_*a*") do set all=!all! "%%c"
  )
  echo !all!
)
```

If for any reason you really need to loop over a file, replace the first `for %%a` loop with a `for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (`

Comment: Are you executing it in the correct directory? Are there `*_v1.mxf` files?

Comment: Yes, they are in the directory

Comment: the output gives, the file names of the two videos, but not the matching audios

Comment: Ok, i think i see the issue. the a* was refering to any number, like a wild card. is there a way to check all numbers between A1 to A8 in that line

Comment: OK, got the output to give this, "5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_IRO_RMUSI_SONG_TimayaKingPerryy_KomKom.mxf_V1.MXF.m2v" ""5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_A1.MXF"" ""5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_A2.MXF"" ""5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_A3.MXF"" ""5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_A4.MXF""

Comment: ""5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_A5.MXF"" ""5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_A6.MXF"" ""5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_A7.MXF"" ""5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_A8.MXF""

Comment: but, you can see that the audio files are not showing the full file name?

Comment: That's because the format of the file names differs from what you stated in your question. Let me think about it.

Comment: `*_v1.mxf` and `*_v1.mxf.m2u` isn't the same. Do the audio files also have the double extension `.mxf.m2u`?

Comment: yeah, they do. its the ingested software. thats how it spits it out.